# BeginPaint() not erasing the background

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

[BeginPaint()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation says:

> If the window's class has a background brush, BeginPaint uses that
>   brush to erase the background of the update region before returning.

I have set the brush like this:

```
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
```

I have drawn a bitmap on my Window, and then I asked for a redraw using the following code:

```
RedrawWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
```

and I have this code in `WM_PAINT`:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

So I expected that `BeginPaint()` will erase the bitmap, but the bitmap remained on the Window!

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: You need to add the `RDW_ERASE` flag to have the background erased.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter It worked, but now it's `RedrawWindow()` that is erasing the background and not `BeginPaint()`.

Comment: No it's not. `RedrawWindow` marks the region as needing erasing.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter But I removed the code inside `WM_PAINT`, and the background was erased.

Comment: If you're not handling `WM_ERASEBKGND` and letting it go through to `DefWindowProc` the erasing will be done there.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter So it is not `BeginPaint()` that erases the background or causes a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message to be sent, but rather it is `RedrawWindow()` with `RDW_ERASE` that causes a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message to be sent, correct?

Comment: @Jonathan Potte Note that I am confused about this subject because I have read the following in the Programming Windows (Fith Edition) book: *"During the BeginPaint call, Windows erases the background of the client area if it hasn't been erased already. It erases the background using the brush specified in the hbrBackground field of the WNDCLASS structure used to register the window class."*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Writing this as an answer because the explanation is too long for a comment).

Painting of the client area can be done in two places in the standard Windows model:

`WM_ERASEBKGND` nominally handles erasing the background.
`WM_PAINT` nominally handles drawing things over the background.

If you pass `WM_ERASEBKGND` through to `DefWindowProc`, it will paint the background using the class brush. You have two choices if you want to handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` yourself:

- You can erase the background yourself, and return 1 (or any non-zero value)
- You can do no erasing, and return 0

If you implement the latter option, when you later get a `WM_PAINT` message and call `BeginPaint`, the `fErase` flag of the `PAINTSTRUCT` will be set to `TRUE`, indicating that the background is still marked for erasure.

The `BeginPaint` function itself doesn't do any painting at all, all it does is give you a `DC` that you can paint into. When you call `EndPaint` the region that was previously marked as dirty is "deemed" to have been painted (and erased) and will no longer be marked as dirty.

The division of painting in background erasure and foreground painting is (in my opinion at least) a remnant of the 16 bit world where painting was an expensive operation. If foreground painting also erases the background (e.g. you are drawing a solid block of colour or a solid image) then erasing the background as a separate step is a waste of time, and will often lead to visible flicker. So depending on your application you may wish to ignore the "erase background" step altogether - return `0` from `WM_ERASEBKGND` and in `WM_PAINT` paint the "background and foreground" in a single step.

Comment: Great explanation. My theory of the division of bg-erasing and painting is that it is useful because the WM_PAINT is lazy and usually asynchronous, but WM_ERASEBKGND is synchronous. That is, when you invalidate a window, the WM_ERASEBKGND is sent immediately, but the WM_PAINT is delayed until idle. That way the user will get immediate visual feedback and stop seeing old, possibly confusing data. The drawback is, as you say, the flicker.

Comment: @rodrigo I actually have a feeling that `WM_ERASEBKGND` itself is normally generated by the call to `BeginPaint`, although I can't find a reference to that anywhere right now. Note also that if you pass `WM_PAINT` through to `DefWindowProc` then it will call `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` for you, so this might explain the comment in your book (if I'm right that is, and `BeginPaint` is responsible for sending `WM_ERASEBKGND`).

Comment: (The exception would be `RedrawWindow` with the `RDW_ERASE | RDW_ERASENOW` flags, which presumably sends `WM_ERASEBKGND` internally).

Comment: *"I actually have a feeling that WM_ERASEBKGND itself is normally generated by the call to BeginPaint, although I can't find a reference to that anywhere right now."* Probably this is not what you mean by not finding a reference, but the `BeginPaint()` documentation says: *"BeginPaint sends a WM_ERASEBKGND message to the window"*.

Comment: I think what you are wrong and `WM_ERASEBKGND` is generated (sent) when `InvalidateRect()`. You can check it easily with the debugger (I remember to have done this a long time ago). Of course, `RedrawWindow()` is different, but the usual repaint cycle should be invalidate-erase-paint.

Comment: @joseph_m: You should take the MSDN documentation with a grain of salt. It is not always as accurate as it seems. If you are curious about these issues I reccomend you to use the Spy++ utility that used to be included with VS.

Comment: @joseph_m Heh that was the one place I didn't look, expecting it not to be there :)